# How do I execute this command (curl) in rails? That is, what library contains a tool that allows me to pass an API key this way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, sinatra

Here's the command I need to execute: (using the example API key)

```
curl -v -u 1971800d4d82861d8f2c1651fea4d212:api_token \
-X GET https://www.toggl.com/api/v8/workspaces/777/tasks
```

I am writing a dashing/sinatra based dashboard that shows a summary of the information from our Toggl account. My question is, how to I open this url in sinatra using something like

`open('http://...) do |f|`

A successful curl returns an array (json) that I can parse for the info I need.

I'm not entirely sure how to tackle this. I have some ideas but they aren't well formed enough to properly comment on them. I though I'd bounce this off of you all for inspiration and information.

I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Check out HTTParty. The example in the README shows basically exactly what you're looking to do using auth headers:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty